# Given an array with different types of data. Any function to convert it to proper csv line in python? If not what would be the simplest approach?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to join the following array into a proper csv line (not a file)

#input array

```
x = [2,"Appple", "car,plane",45.2]
```

I tried the following

```
",".join(x)
```

But it fails as the resulting output is 2,Apple,car,plane,45.2 . It also fails due to the numbers and floats.

Expected result would be:

```
2,Apple,"car,plane",45.2
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)…?

Comment: It is not clear what is the difference between "resulting output" and "expected result".

Comment: @Gino The missing quotes.

Comment: "car,plane" is a single string, the resulting output treats them as separate. 
The expected one still treats it as a single string as it is enclosed in double quotes

Comment: You can also extend your approach slightly to work for your toy example if that is the only thing you care about: `",".join([f'"{i}"' if ',' in str(i) else str(i) for i in x])`

Answer (score 0):

The code above will output the following string: `z= "2, 'Appple', 'car,plane', 45.2"`

```
x = [2, "Appple", "car,plane", 45.2]
z = f"{x}"
z = z.replace("[","")
z = z.replace("]", "")
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is that he wish to have a string which can then be inserted in the .csv. The code above will output a `z= "2, 'Appple', 'car,plane', 45.2" `

Answer (score -1):

A simple approach would be using pandas: `pd.DataFrame(x).to_csv()`. Or using the csv module:

```
import csv
import io

out = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(out) 
writer.writerow(x)
csv_string = out.getvalue()
out.close()
```

Comment: Where "simple" means "include a giant dependency"…

Comment: @deceze and why is that a problem? Is he going to distribute his novel list to csv conversion package?

Comment: This functionality is natively available in the `csv` module, even if it may be two more lines of code…

Comment: While that may be the case, it is not uncommon that somebody already has pandas installed or doesn't care installing it.